# Random.randint on lists in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, random

I want to create a list and fill it with 15 zeros, then I want to change the 0 to 1 in 5 random spots of the list, so it has 10 zeros and 5 ones, here is what I tried

```
import random, time

dasos = []

for i in range(1, 16):
  dasos.append(0)

for k in range(1, 6):
  dasos[random.randint(0, 15)] = 1
```

Sometimes I would get anywhere from 0 to 5 ones but I want exactly 5 ones, 
if I add:

```
print(dasos)
```

...to see my list I get:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Perhaps you'll be fine using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: Use `randrange(0, 15)` or `randint(0, 14)`

Comment: As @Gassa says, `random.sample(range(15), 5)` will give you 5 unique numbers between 0 and 14.

Comment: Another way to do it could be to first save all possible indices outside the loop (e.g. `canditates = range(15)`), shuffle this list with `random.shuffle(candidates)`, and then use the first 5 numbers as your indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
my_lst = [0 for _ in range(15)]

for i in random.sample(range(15), 5):
    my_lst[i] = 1
```

You could also consider using [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and use the first 5 entries:

```
my_lst = [0 for _ in range(15)]
candidates = list(range(15))
random.shuffle(candidates)

for i in candidates[0:5]:
    my_lst[i] = 1
```

TL;DR: Read the the Python [random documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), this can be done in multiple ways.

Comment: I didn't suggest any of these things because clearly this would only cause confusion to the OP, which apparently is very new to programming. In my opinion, things like list-comprehensions are incredibly horrible for learning programming. My solution might not be on purpose the most pythonic one, but it is more intuitive for a beginner.

Comment: If you really want to learn how to program a today's computer, then learn C.

Comment: Note that the `random.choice` implementation has the same problem as the Questioner's original code: It might pick the same index more than once. The `shuffle` solution also needs to be tweaked to work in Python 3, where `range` returns a non-list iterable. Use `candidates = list(range(15))` to ensure you get an actual list that can be shuffled.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the comments. I was "sure" that `random.choice` popped the elements, but apparently my memory served me wrong :-) Also I didn't notice that the question was about Python 3, so thank you for notifying me.

Comment: @nbro The OP already use a method from the `random` library in his code. Pointing out that he's using the wrong method is _obviously_ correct rather than trying to hack something together that works with his choice of method.

Comment: @SteinarLima IMO he's not using the wrong method for his purposes.